# How would I prove my claim in a class action settlement on a "stock misconduct" case when I shorted the stock?

Tags: stocks, shorting-securities, lawsuit-settlement

In order to participate in a net settlement fund, a claimant must have "purchased or otherwise acquired stock". If I shorted does the stock did I "purchase it or otherwise acquire it"?

Comment: If you covered your short position, you certainly did "purchase" the shares needed to do that, but without more context it's impossible to say whether that really counts toward participation in the settlement.

Answer (score 3):

No. **You shorted the stock so you are not a shareholder**. If you covered your short, again you are not a shareholder as you statement of account must show. You cannot participate in the net settlement fund.